# How do I view an organisation member's email in Trello?

Tags: email, trello

In Trello, I created an organisation with several members. I need to get the email of one of the members, in order to invite them to a new separate board. Can I get the email address of an existing member of one of my boards from Trello?

Answer (score 4):

While you can't get their email directly, if you head to the organization's profile page from your [boards page](https://trello.com/me/boards), you can find the users' square, click on it, and click their name in the popup to get to their profile page. Here you can note their username in parenthesis, and you may enter this into the invitation input box to invite them to your board.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, it is possible to guess email addresses by trying to re-invite those addresses to a workspace or organization.